# Estimated shipping not showing on cart and checkout page in Magento-2

Tags: magento2

I am not getting shipping on either cart or checkout page and I got this error on console: Cannot read property 'is_zipcode_optional' of undefined.

When I click on city and zipcode input filed on checkout page than it starts displaying shipping method.

I have tried to solve this issue but didn't get any solution.

Thanks in advance for your help.